# Disclaimer Popup Request

Tags: 2013, web-part, sharepoint-server, site-collection, access

I'm searching for a solution with third party web parts, but at this time I don't find anything that is aligned with my search.

The target:

- When a user login in to the portal (link to home or link to a customer list, etc) the system displays a disclaimer popup that block all user actions (navigation, access to the content, etc) and awaits the users decision.
- In case the user accept the disclaimer, the system have to trace the decision, unlock all actions, and not require it in the future.
- In case the user not accept the disclaimer, the system have to trace the decision and redirect the user (link or dedicated page).

Important points:

- The users choice has to be easily managed (ie: stored in a custom
  list)
- The web parts has to work across site collecions (>5)
- Centralized management of disclaimer text

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Add a pop-up tag to SharePoint master page. Manage the display of the pop-up and page using CSS.
- Based on whether user accepts or rejects the disclaimer, define script functions.
- On acceptance, set some value in User Profile properties to validate his/her choice for the next time the user logs in. For some pointers on doing the same, you may have a look at this msdn [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj920104.aspx)
- Define a function on document load to check if the logged in user has accepted or rejected the disclaimer based on the User Profile property that was set earlier.
- Based on the value fetched, toggle between the CSS classes for displaying the page / pop-up.

You can use the same master page across site collections and since the User Profile properties are stored at the farm level, you will be able to validate the user's choice.